# regex for python (version number - date format)

Tags: python, regex

I have a file like this. The format of the version is `<version> space(s) dash space(s) date`. I want to create a dictionary with `4.11.1 - 2020-02-25` as key and everything after that before `3.25.0 - 2019-01-01` as value and so on till the end of the file.

```
##################
Some texts

4.11.1 - 2020-02-25
-------------------

*some text

** Some more text

3.25.0 - 2019-01-01
-------------------

*some text

** Some more text
```

This is what I tried:

```
result ={}
matches = re.findall(r'([\d.]+[^\n]+)\s*(.*?)(?=\s*[\d.]+[^\n]+|$)', Text, re.S)
for match in matches:
    result[match[0]] = match[1]
 print(result)
```

It works for most of the cases. But it also prints these as keys :

```
.com/sth/sth/sth/6)

1.8.2 (https://github.com/sth/sth/sth/5)

1.8.1.

20160918 (see commands under 'some text')

. text text tex
```

Comment: What code/regex have you written to achieve this and what exactly is the issue with it?

Comment: edited my attempt in the question.

Comment: You could use 2 capturing groups `^(\d+(?:\.\d+)+ - \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\r?\n((?:(?!\d+\.\d).*(?:\r?\n|$))*)` https://regex101.com/r/dxEkrg/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use 2 capturing groups, and instead of using `re.S` use `re.M`

The pattern will capture in **group 1** a version and space(s) dash space(s) using `\d+(?:.\d+)+ +- +` followed by a date like pattern `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}`

Note that is does not validate a date itself. [This page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html) shows how you can make that date pattern more specific.

The capture **group 2** matches all lines that do not start with 1+ digits, a dot and a digit. You can make that part more specific if you want.

```
^(\d+(?:\.\d+)+ +- +\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\r?\n((?:(?!\d+\.\d).*(?:\r?\n|$))*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QTrO9P/1)

```
import re

result ={}
Text = ("##################\n"
    "Some texts\n\n"
    "4.11.1 - 2020-02-25\n"
    "-------------------\n\n"
    "*some text\n\n"
    "** Some more text\n\n"
    "3.25.0 - 2019-01-01\n"
    "-------------------\n\n"
    "*some text\n\n"
    "** Some more text")
matches = re.findall(r'^(\d+(?:\.\d+)+ +- +\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\r?\n((?:(?!\d+\.\d).*(?:\r?\n|$))*)', Text, re.M)

for match in matches:
    result[match[0]] = match[1]
print(result)
```

*Output*

```
{'4.11.1 - 2020-02-25': '-------------------\n\n*some text\n\n** Some more text\n\n', '3.25.0 - 2019-01-01': '-------------------\n\n*some text\n\n** Some more text'}
```

Comment: Nice job! I think the only generalization teased in the question (but not made use of in the sample input) is that there might be multiple spaces between the dash and the version and between the dash and the date, respectively.

Comment: @DavidWierichs Sharp!  Thank you, I have updated it. If there can be whitspace chars except newlines, it could also become `[^\S\r\n]*-[^\S\r\n]*`

Comment: Group 2 will always start from a string where the first char is Capital. Something like this. 
I tried to change (?:(?!\d+\.\d).*(?:\r?\n|$) part to ^(\d+(?:\.\d+)+ +- +\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\r?\n((?:([A-Z][a-z]+).*(?:\r?\n|$))*) but didnt work. 
4.11.1 - 2020-02-25


-------------------
Changed